# What governs the order of linked text frames in Scribus?

Tags: text, scribus

I'm in the process of laying a document out using Scribus, and I've noticed an odd behaviour - I'm using a two-page spread and the text on the right-side pages flows from the rightmost text frame first into the left frame.

This is weird, and I'd like to know how to change the behaviour so that the text frames flow in a more sensible order. I'd also understand what's driving this behaviour so I can adjust my workflow to avoid the problem in the future.

How does Scribus decide what order to apply to the frames when flowing text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally, you create the frames and chain them together.

The order in which you chain the frames does matter.

You can see the order by activating *View > Text frames > Show text chain* (this is for Scribus 1.5; in 1.4 it's very similar).